# Low voltage cutoff circuit with PV panel

Tags: voltage, low-power, low-voltage

I'm trying to build a simple reliable low voltage cutoff circuit and sufficient voltage turn on circuit for a PV panel powered circuit. The idea was to supply power from PV panel to a working circuit when sufficient Power is available else cut it off from the panel. 
I tried to build a simple circuit to achieve this but It's quite not working reliably. I was trying to trigger a sugar cube relay (12v) when sufficient voltage is available at the panel. Please take a look at the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frDaPe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem I'm facing is Its collector to emitter voltage is not dropping to its near saturated value even if the base is supplied with the current and relay does not turn on.

Thank you community for lots of help in the past.

Edit :

Driving a thyristor  using BJT.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe4JyW.png)</sup>

Comment: Your question is not clear to me: you are saying that if you short D1 and supply the base of Q1 with a current, then the collector voltage of Q1 is not dropping to 0V?

Comment: yes. In short transistor is not switching on. I was expecting around 0.8v across Vce when transistor turns on.

Comment: This circuit might oscillate under certain circumstances. When the PV delivers just enough voltage to turn on Q1, the load is connected. That increase in load will make the PV voltage drop slightly making Q1 switch off. Then the load is switched off so the PV voltage can increase, then repeat... To solve this you could add some hysteresis by adding positive feedback (perhaps using a spare relay contact), for example to switch a Zener diode with a slightly lower voltage in parallel with D1.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it using a parallel diode with D1. Just out of brainstorming.. How about adding a thyristor at the output with gate driven by the current from the transistor. I'm attaching the circuit I thought of please let me know you thoughts. Thank you very much

Comment: Problems with Thyristor circuit: 1) the load should be between supply and anode. Like it is now, the thyristor might not be triggered properly. 2) how do you turn **off** the thyristor? The thyristor would only turn at night when there's no light on the PV panel.

Comment: No doubt messing with some components like this is fun :-) However, for a easy, straightforward and reliable solution I'd use some microcontroller, feed it from a 5 V regulator (mind the 40 V input voltage or use a zener diode to drop some voltage). Make the micro switch on/off an NMOS, use NMOS to switch on/off 24 V relay with series resistance. Use resistor voltage divider and micro's ADC to measure voltage. Write program to dis(connect) load when I want. Done. Electronics is too easy these days ;-)

Comment: Or (if you fear microcontrollers :-) just use a schmitt trigger (hysteresis).

Comment: Thank you all for your very useful comments. @Bimpelrekkie I think I shift the load above the thyristor to turn the load on and get a common ground for the transistor and thyristor. For now turn of isn't a bigger concern and when the current falls below the holding current of the thyristor, I guess it automatically turns off. The main concern is how to turn the whole circuit on when a sufficient voltage is available from the panel. I suppose shifting the load would do the job.

Comment: @StefanWyss Using microcontroller isn't an issue but it would unnecessarily increases the cost where it needs a supply of 5V step-down from the panel (LM2596 would do the trick) but increases the cost. and using a thyristor I guess would get an inherent reverse voltage protection and that's a neat plus for this system. I just hope the thyristor circuit works!!

Comment: I would still go with the first circuit and the relay and additionally use a comparator with hysteresis to turn the relay on/off via a transistor.

Comment: @StefanWyss The first circuit with relay did work but there are some modifications. An external stable supply was needed at the collector. I provided a 12v using lm2596 (there wasn't another way) right from the panel itself. But as you suggested the relay did oscillate quite a lot at the transition period. I've researched quite a lot on schmitt trigger but a bit confused to implement in this circuit. I tried paralleling the  zener diodes.. didn't help It had the same effect(oscillations)